# Using options with :tabe in vim

Tags: vim, tabs

I have a file open in Vim.

I'd like to open another file in a tab, using the :tabe command. However, I'd also like to open this file with the -M option, in order to avoid modification and writing of the file. I tried to use the following command in vim:

```
:tabe -M filename
```

However, that did not work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
:tabe +set\ nomodifiable|set\ ro filename
```

Using `+` after tabe lets you specify a set of commands to run when opening the file. For more details, see

```
:help +cmd
```

If this is something you do often, you can set up a custom command to do this for you

```
:command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Tabread tabe +set\ nomodifiable|set\ ro <args>
```

Place that in your .vimrc to have it whenever you start vim.

This command will create a new user command called `Tabread` that supports filename completion (so you can use it like `tabe`). It sets those options for you and opens the file in a new tab.

The `nomodifiable` option prevents editing commands from working on the buffer, and the `ro` option prefents writing the buffer to disk.